How to apply shadow to an SVG?
I want to apply a shadow like effect (but not using box-shadow) to an SVG image that doesn't have a box or container like shape. The SVG is a custom shape and downloaded as a file from the web - so doesn't contain any typical Path type objects like what is used in CustomPaint or CustomClipper.

You can use the BoxShadow class along with the Container widget to wrap your SVG icon.

 Material(
      elevation: 1.5,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      child: SVG ICON()

or second is
Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 40.0, 20.0, 40.0),
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: const Color(0xFF66BB6A),
      boxShadow: [new BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black,
        blurRadius: 20.0,
      ),]
    ),
    child: SVG ICON()


You can apply SVG shadow using this way
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
              spreadRadius: 5,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: Offset(0, 3),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          'your SVG file path',
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
        ),
      ),

